# How do I filter to rows with all cap strings?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, stringr

I am trying to figure out a way to filter to rows with all cap strings.

For example, say I have the following data frame:

```
col1 <- c("Hello my NAME is", "How are YOU", "I'm doing well")
col2 <- c("Thank YOU", "How are you doing?", "Life is HARD")
col3 <- c("I'm sorry to hear", "That's how it GOES", "RIGHT")

df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3)
```

1. I want to be able to use filter (from dplyr) on col1 to the first
   and second rows (the rows with the caps)
2. I want to be able filter col2 to the first and third rows
3. I want to be able to filter col3 to the second and third rows

I assume the structure would be something like this:

```
df %>%
  filter(
    str_detect(col1, "[A-Z]+")
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_dfc(df, 
      ~ str_subset(.x, "\\b[A-Z]{2,}\\b"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  col1             col2         col3              
  <chr>            <chr>        <chr>             
1 Hello my NAME is Thank YOU    That's how it GOES
2 How are YOU      Life is HARD RIGHT
```

Comment: What does `\\b[A-Z]{2,}\\b` mean explicitly?

Comment: @hy9fesh `\\b` is word boundary followed by 2 or more upper case letters and then a word boundary.